# Spring 4 RestController - How to return jaxb object with ResponseEntity

Tags: spring, rest, jaxb

I am using Spring @RESTController for my REST webservice. instead of returning the object of ModelAndView I am trying to return the object of ResponseEntity object in my rest method. for the Strgin type of response it is working ut when I am building ResponseEntity with a Jaxbobject it is giving me HTTP error 406

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/service")
public class MyController {
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> getDashBoardData() throws JAXBException {
    // Some Operation
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(myStringXML, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Below is not working

```
    @RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/service")
public class MyController {
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<MyJaxbClass> getDashBoardData() throws JAXBException {
    // Some Operation
        return new ResponseEntity<MyJaxbClass>(MyJaxbClassObject, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: When using `@RestController` you don't need to the `@ResponseBody` that is implied. Also make sure that you have configured the mvc stuff correctly to marshall jaxb objects.

Comment: Removing the @ResponseBody annotation does not help. Here I have a confusion that if I return a ModelAndView than I could specify the view resolver for jaxb but Here I am returning ResponseEntity, Can you please give some pointer that how I could add a view resolver for ResponseEntity

Comment: Post some of your related configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@RestController` annotation already implies the `@ResponseBody` annotation for all request handling methods, that is one of its purposes (it saves you from putting all those annotations there). So you can/should remove it.

Processing the return value of the method is done by a 'HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`and the specific one which should handle this delegates to a`HttpMessageConverter`. It selects a specific`HttpMessageConverter`based on the requested/supported response types for the current request and the support response types from the`HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`.

In general when using `@EnableWebMvc` or `<mvc:annotation-driven />` everything should be setup automatically. The automatic setup does some detection on which libs are available (jaxb, json etc).

Based on the response code (406) you either have manually configured something wrong on the server side or the client doesn't support xml as a response type.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not specified <mvc:annotation-driven />, It was the issue.